# Database Error at /myapp/

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I just include a choice field in my model

```
quote_template = models.CharField(_('Template'), choices=TEMPLATE, max_length=20)
```

and now this error is coming

```
DatabaseError at /quote/
current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

any idea??? how to resolve this??

Comment: That's not the error you're looking for.  When postgres gets an error mid transaction, it then produces the current transaction is aborted error on all subsequent requests.  You need to look back in your logs for the error that started it all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding fields to your model will not magically update the existing database schema - you either have to do it by and or use a schema-migration tool like South.

Comment: I have done that  ./manage.py schemamigration quote --auto and then ./manage.py migrate quote